# Select count(*) different from exapain rows

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I'm trying to generate new index on a table in order to get fastest querys.
My table called 'conexiones' :

```
    CREATE TABLE `conexiones` (
      `idConexion` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idInstalacion` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `idUsuario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tMacAdres` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tUsuario` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tNombre` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tApellido` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tEmail` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSexo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fNacimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nAmigos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tPoblacion` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fFecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tEvento` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idConexion`),
  KEY `idInstalacion` (`idInstalacion`),
  KEY `tMacAdress` (`tMacAdres`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fFecha` (`fFecha`),
  KEY `idUsuario` (`idUsuario`),
  KEY `insta_fecha` (`idInstalacion`,`fFecha`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2365270 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has 2365270 rows.

What I don't undestand is that running that query:

```
select count(*) from conexiones 
    where    conexiones.idInstalacion=190
```

The return value is: 59314

But if I insert EXPLAIN table the return is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  conexiones  ref idInstalacion,insta_fecha   idInstalacion   5   const   108830  "Using index"
```

108830 rows ?

Why is searching more rows than the total rows I got from count(*) ?

(Add new info)

This is show index from connexions

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
conexiones  0   PRIMARY 1   idConexion  A   2304649 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
conexiones  1   idInstalacion   1   idInstalacion   A   2658    NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
conexiones  1   tMacAdress  1   tMacAdres   A   2304649 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
conexiones  1   fFecha  1   fFecha  A   2304649 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
conexiones  1   idUsuario   1   idUsuario   A   2304649 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
conexiones  1   insta_fecha 1   idInstalacion   A   1422    NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
conexiones  1   insta_fecha 2   fFecha  A   2304649 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

idInstalacion differents values show be arround 1000

Table conexiones has 2.365.270 rows.

At the end the query that is getting slow when is not on memory, 15s the first time, 2s or 0,6s second times, is:

```
select count(distinct(concat(conexiones.tMacAdres,date_format(conexiones.fFecha,'%Y%m%d')))) as Conexiones,
                    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',1,0)) as MeGusta,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosMeGusta,
                    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',1,0)) as CheckIn,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosCheckIn,
                    min(conexiones.fFecha) Fecha_Inicio, now() Fecha_fin,datediff(now(),min(conexiones.fFecha)) as dias
                    from conexiones, instalaciones
                    where  conexiones.idInstalacion=instalaciones.idInstalacion and conexiones.idInstalacion=190
                        and (fFecha between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-06-18 23:59:59')
                    group by instalaciones.tNombre
                    order by instalaciones.idCliente
```

Thanks !

Comment: For the second query you should ask a new question, because it's a different subject. Don't forget to post EXPLAIN and schema for both tables.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't know how many rows will match the condition when you run EXPLAIN. The number in the `rows` column is a statistical estimation.

> The **rows** column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must
>   examine to execute the query.
>
> For *InnoDB* tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be
>   exact.

[(EXPLAIN Output Format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows)

> The average value group size is related to table cardinality, which is
>   the number of value groups. The [SHOW INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html) statement displays a
>   cardinality value based on *`N/S`*, where *`N`* is the number of rows in the
>   table and *`S`* is the average value group size. That ratio yields an
>   approximate number of value groups in the table.

[(InnoDB and MyISAM Index Statistics Collection)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-statistics.html)

So if your table has 10M rows and the `idInstalacion` column contains about 100 distinct values, then the average group size would be about 100K. Now one group might have 50K rows and another group 150K rows. But again - MySQL doesn't know that before executing the query - So it uses the average.

Comment: According to the official reference: "The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query. For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact." [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows)

Comment: @OscarJofre, what is the cardinality for `idInstalacion`? Run `show index from conexiones`. And what is the overall number of rows in that table?

Comment: @OscarJofre, the cardinality of 2658 doesn't seem to explain the number (108830) in the EXPLAIN output. I would expect something like 1000 (2365270/2658). MySQL seems to use some other statistics.

Comment: The "100" is also approximated -- by doing a small number of "dives" into the BTree.  Bottom line:  Don't trust the Explain numbers.  Yet they "usually" lead to the best way to perform the query.  Improvements may be coming in 5.8.